# Android Search Function With Custom ListView Using BaseAdapter And Edit Text

Tags: android, listview

Hi I've been searching google for a few hours now looking for ways to implement the search filter / function into my custom listview

my main xml file consists of an edit text and a list view item
and my single row xml consists of 2x textview and 1x image view

my problem is that I cannot seem to get the search to work
any references, ideas or otherwise would be greatly appreciated

NB app is still under development so please excuse any incomplete stubs

here's my code:

```
        public class KantoDex extends Activity {
             ListView l;
             EditText inputSearch;
            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
               setContentView(R.layout.kantodex);
               l = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
               l.setAdapter(new AdapterHand(this));
               inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });

}

class viewHolder {
    ImageView myImage;
    TextView myTitle;
    TextView myDescription;

    viewHolder(View v) {
        myTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        myDescription = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        myImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    }
}
class SingleRow {
    String title;
    String description;
    int balls;

    SingleRow(String title, String description, int balls) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.balls = balls;


    }


}
class AdapterHand extends BaseAdapter {
    private List<SingleRow> list2 = null;
    private ArrayList<SingleRow> arraylist;

    ArrayList<SingleRow> list;
    Context context;
    ArrayList<SingleRow> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    AdapterHand(Context c) {
        context = c;
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        Resources res = c.getResources();
        String[] title = res.getStringArray(R.array.kantotitles);
        String[] description = res.getStringArray(R.array.kantoids);
        int[] balls = {R.drawable.kantobulbasaur, R.drawable.kantoivysaur, R.drawable.kantovenusaur,
                       R.drawable.kantocharmander, R.drawable.kantocharmeleon, R.drawable.kantocharizard,
                       R.drawable.kantosquirtle, R.drawable.kantowartortle, R.drawable.kantoblastoise,
                       R.drawable.kantocaterpie, R.drawable.kantometapod, R.drawable.kantobutterfree,
                       R.drawable.kanto, R.drawable.johto, R.drawable.hoenn,
                       R.drawable.sinnoh, R.drawable.unova, R.drawable.kalos,
                       R.drawable.kanto, R.drawable.johto, R.drawable.hoenn,
                       R.drawable.sinnoh, R.drawable.unova, R.drawable.kalos,
                       R.drawable.kanto, R.drawable.johto, R.drawable.hoenn,
                       R.drawable.sinnoh, R.drawable.unova, R.drawable.kalos,
                       R.drawable.kanto, R.drawable.johto, R.drawable.hoenn, R.drawable.sinnoh, R.drawable.unova,
                       R.drawable.kalos,R.drawable.kanto, R.drawable.johto, R.drawable.hoenn, R.drawable.sinnoh,
                       R.drawable.unova, R.drawable.kalos,R.drawable.kanto, R.drawable.johto, R.drawable.hoenn,
                       R.drawable.sinnoh, R.drawable.unova, R.drawable.kalos,R.drawable.kanto, R.drawable.johto,
                       R.drawable.hoenn, R.drawable.sinnoh, R.drawable.unova, R.drawable.kalos,R.drawable.kanto,
                       R.drawable.johto, R.drawable.hoenn, R.drawable.sinnoh, R.drawable.unova, R.drawable.kalos,
                       R.drawable.kanto, R.drawable.johto, R.drawable.hoenn, R.drawable.sinnoh, R.drawable.unova,
                       R.drawable.kalos,R.drawable.kanto, R.drawable.johto, R.drawable.hoenn, R.drawable.sinnoh,
                       R.drawable.unova, R.drawable.kalos,R.drawable.kanto, R.drawable.johto, R.drawable.hoenn,
                       R.drawable.sinnoh, R.drawable.unova, R.drawable.kalos,R.drawable.kanto, R.drawable.johto,
                       R.drawable.hoenn, R.drawable.sinnoh, R.drawable.unova, R.drawable.kalos,R.drawable.kanto,
                       R.drawable.johto, R.drawable.hoenn, R.drawable.sinnoh, R.drawable.unova, R.drawable.kalos,
                       R.drawable.kanto, R.drawable.johto, R.drawable.hoenn, R.drawable.sinnoh, R.drawable.unova,
                       R.drawable.kalos,R.drawable.kanto, R.drawable.johto, R.drawable.hoenn, R.drawable.sinnoh,
                       R.drawable.unova, R.drawable.kalos,R.drawable.kanto, R.drawable.johto, R.drawable.hoenn,
                       R.drawable.sinnoh, R.drawable.unova, R.drawable.kalos,R.drawable.kanto, R.drawable.johto,
                       R.drawable.hoenn, R.drawable.sinnoh, R.drawable.unova, R.drawable.kalos,R.drawable.kanto,
                       R.drawable.johto, R.drawable.hoenn, R.drawable.sinnoh, R.drawable.unova, R.drawable.kalos,
                       R.drawable.kanto, R.drawable.johto, R.drawable.hoenn, R.drawable.sinnoh, R.drawable.unova,
                       R.drawable.kalos,R.drawable.kanto, R.drawable.johto, R.drawable.hoenn, R.drawable.sinnoh,
                       R.drawable.unova, R.drawable.kalos,R.drawable.kanto, R.drawable.johto, R.drawable.hoenn,
                       R.drawable.sinnoh, R.drawable.unova, R.drawable.kalos,R.drawable.kanto, R.drawable.johto,
                       R.drawable.hoenn, R.drawable.sinnoh, R.drawable.unova, R.drawable.kalos,R.drawable.kanto,
                       R.drawable.johto, R.drawable.hoenn, R.drawable.sinnoh, R.drawable.unova, R.drawable.kalos,
                       R.drawable.kanto, R.drawable.johto, R.drawable.hoenn, R.drawable.sinnoh,
                       R.drawable.unova, R.drawable.kalos,R.drawable.kanto};
        for (int i = 0; i < 151; i++) {
            list.add(new SingleRow(title[i], description[i], balls[i]));
        }


    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return list.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View row = convertView;
        viewHolder holder = null;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, null, false);
            holder = new viewHolder(row);
            row.setTag(holder);
            Log.d("MetaDex", "Creating");
        } else {
            holder = (viewHolder) row.getTag();
            Log.d("MetaDex", "Recycling");
        }

        SingleRow temp = list.get(i);

        holder.myTitle.setText(temp.title);
        holder.myDescription.setText(temp.description);
        holder.myImage.setImageResource(temp.balls);

        return row;
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your adapter with code below for search feature.

```
class AdapterHand extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<SingleRow> list = new ArrayList<SingleRow>();
    private ArrayList<SingleRow> filteredList = new ArrayList<SingleRow>();
    private boolean searchEnabled = false;
    private String searchTerm;

    // Your constructor
    //
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if(searchEnabled)
            return filteredList.size();
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // Your viewholder pattern

        SingleRow temp = searchEnabled ? filteredList.get(position) : list.get(position);

        // Set text, etc. from temp

        holder.myTitle.setText(temp.title);
        holder.myDescription.setText(temp.description);
        holder.myImage.setImageResource(temp.balls);

        return convertView;
    }

    public void setSearchEnabled(boolean enabled, String text) {
        searchEnabled = enabled;
        if(!searchEnabled) {
            searchTerm = "";
            filteredList.clear();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            return;
        }
        searchTerm = text.toLowerCase();
        filter();
    }

    private void filter() {
        filteredList.clear();
        if(searchTerm.length() == 0) {
            filteredList.addAll(list);
        } else if(searchTerm.length() == 1) {
            for(SingleRow row : list) {
                if(row.getTitle().toLowerCase().charAt(0) == searchTerm.toLowerCase().charAt(0))
                    filteredList.add(row);
            }

        } else {
            for(SingleRow row : list) {
                if(row.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(searchTerm)) {
                    filteredList.add(row);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }





}
```

Then put the lines below in `onTextChanged()`

```
String searchText = inputSearch.getText().toString();
mAdapter.setSearchEnabled(true, searchText); //mAdapter is an instance of the AdapterHand that you keep a reference of in your Activity
```

To cancel search call

```
mAdapter.setSearchEnabled(false, "");
```

Comment: oh I see right I was trying to implement it that way but couldn't figure out how to do it without making a new arraylist which then would have nothing to do with the single row item

Answer (score 0):

For your reference, of course it can be different in your project because my code is for ExpandableListView, however, I think the logic is the same. Hope this helps!

MainActivity.java:

```
...
import android.widget.SearchView;
...

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
        SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, SearchView.OnCloseListener {
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        
        ...
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        searchView.setOnCloseListener(this);
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public boolean onClose() {
        if (adapter != null) {
            adapter.filterData("");
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        if (adapter != null) {
            adapter.filterData(query);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        if (adapter != null) {
            adapter.filterData(newText);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

In adapter class:

```
public void filterData(String query) {

        query = query.toLowerCase();
        mListDataHeader.clear();

        if (query.isEmpty()) {
            mListDataHeader.addAll(mListDataHeader_org);
        } else {

            for (String header : mListDataHeader_org) {
                if (header.toLowerCase().contains(query)) {
                    mListDataHeader.add(header);
                }
            }
        }

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: Upvote is also another way of saying thanks, of course if you find my answer helpful!